# Is all data going into Azure, regardless of source, free?

Tags: azure

Sources of data going  into Azure can come from say Scheduled Job retrieving data from the internet at regular intervals, users sending data from their devices, into database tables or large files for storage into blob storage etc.

Is it true all inbound sources of data such as these are free?  Just when data leaves Azure is it charged?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: **yes**.

Check the pricing calculator: http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/pricing/calculator/?scenario=full

More detail here: http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/pricing/details/data-transfers/

For bandwidth, it says this:

> All inbound data sent to Windows Azure is free. Outbound data is
>   charged based on the total amount of data moving out of the Windows
>   Azure datacenters via the Internet in a given billing cycle. Data
>   transfers between Windows Azure services located within the same
>   datacenter are not subject to any charge. The first 5 GB of outbound
>   data transfers per billing month are also free.

Comment: thank you I saw that as well, just wanted to verify, it seemed too good to be true. Glad that its true